# Use String as Variable Name Python

Tags: python, object

I am trying to make a database of baseball stats and lineups. Is there a way to loop through a list of teams and use a string as an variable name?

For example:
Extract team name

```
team_name = 'BOS'
```

Use BOS as variable name for object and append to list of objects

```
BOS = team_data()
teams.append(BOS)
```

Then when I index some stats, I can do the following to retrieve the lineup:

```
teams.BOS.lineup
```

I know in Matlab you can do the following and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in Python:

```
teams.(team_name).lineup
```

Currently I have it assigning the data to the same variable name each loop and appending to the list.

```
teams[0].team_name = 'BOS'
teams[1].team_name = 'NYY'
```

My only other thought is to have a switch case for team_name to assign to the team variable name.

Comment: `for team_name in teams:`?

Comment: The equivalent of your matlab example is `getattr(teams, team_name).lineup` . You can also `setattr(teams, team_name, team_data())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dictionary:

```
teams = {}

teams['BOS'] = team_data()   
teams['NYY'] = team_data() 

for key in teams:
    print(teams[key].team_name) # removed the quotes around "key"
```

Comment: Do the team name strings have to be preset, or can it be done when I get the string of the team name?

Comment: They don't have to be preset. You can create keys dynamically.